# What does the scipy.stats.t.fit() method return?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scipy.stats

I have a set of data points sampled from a normal distribution.

```py
mu, sigma = 0, 1
x = rng.normal(mu, sigma, 100)
```

I add outliers to the initial set

```py
outliers =  np.random.uniform(low=6, high=7, size=10)

# Concatenate original samples with outliers
x = np.append(x, outliers)
y = stats.norm.pdf(x, 0, 1)
```

I then try to find the new distribution

```py
# Find new mean and standard deviation
mu_new, sigma_new = stats.norm.fit(x)
# Get new distribution
y_norm_new = stats.norm.pdf(x_norm, mu_new, sigma_new)
```

And here is where I get stuck: I want to fit the t-distribution to the same data (`x`). However, `stats.t.fit(x)` returns three values:

```py
unknown_value_maybe_df, mu_t, sigma_t = stats.t.fit(x)
```

I assume the first value is the degree of freedom. Is this correct? I cannot find a confirmation in the documentation. The only certainty is that the last two are `loc` and `scale`. The first one is an ["Estimates for any shape parameters (if applicable)"](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit).

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit

Comment: Yes, the first one is the degrees of freedom.